# pyspark: dataframe select row by id in another dataframe's column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to

1. filter df1 by `time_create==last_timestamp`,
2. filter df2  by selected `store_product_id` from df1

---

Here I only use df1 for example,

Select by time_create is nice :

```
df1[df1.time_create==last_timestamp].show()
```

[image]

However, use the selected `store_product_id`, filter original dataframe `df1` gave me a lot of rows.

```
df1[df1.store_product_id.isin(df1[df1.time_create==last_timestamp].store_product_id)].show()
```

[image]

I also tried collect `store_product_id` list which match `time_create==last_timestamp` .

```
ids = df1[df1.time_create==last_timestamp].select('store_product_id').collect()
df1[df1.store_product_id.isin(ids)].show()
```

But got error :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [01e8f3c0-3ad5-4b69-b46d-f5feb3cadd5f]
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:164)
    at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.create(literals.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.typedLit(functions.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit(functions.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

What is the correct way ?

Comment: Replace `.select('store_product_id')` by `.select(['store_product_id'])` ?

Comment: @ma3oun  `.select('store_product_id')`  is working. The error come from `df1[df1.store_product_id.isin(ids)]` .  Seems `isin` only accept python list or tuple . But the previous code even not failed , very strange .

Comment: The collected `ids` are probably in the form of a list Row data structures, I am guessing you need a list of values, so use `toPandas` instead of collect and then extract the list of values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ags29 said,

The result of `df1[df1.time_create==last_timestamp].select(['store_product_id']).collect()` is list of Row :

```
[Row(store_product_id=u'01e8f3c0-3ad5-4b69-b46d-f5feb3cadd5f')]
```

I need convert the row to string,  correct way is :

```
ids = df1[df1.time_create==last_timestamp].select('store_product_id').collect()
ids = map(lambda x: x.store_product_id, ids)
df1[df1.store_product_id.isin(ids)].show()
```

This is quite different with pandas .

Answer (score 3):

The function you are looking for is `join`. Here is a simple example based on your data:

```
import pyspark as sp
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

samples = [{'store_product_id':1,'time_create':2,'last_timestamp':3},{'store_product_id':2,'time_create':2,'last_timestamp':2},{'store_product_id':3,'time_create':4,'last_timestamp':4},{'store_product_id':4,'time_create':2,'last_timestamp':5}]

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName('test') \
        .getOrCreate()

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(samples)
df1.show()
```

This yields:

```
+--------------+----------------+-----------+
|last_timestamp|store_product_id|time_create|
+--------------+----------------+-----------+
|             3|               1|          2|
|             2|               2|          2|
|             4|               3|          4|
|             5|               4|          2|
+--------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Let's filter on time and create another dataframe from that:

```
df2 = df1.filter(df1.time_create==df1.last_timestamp)
ids = df2.select('store_product_id').show()

+----------------+
|store_product_id|
+----------------+
|               2|
|               3|
+----------------+
```

And this is where we join both datasets on *store_product_id*:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2,'store_product_id','inner').show()

+----------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|store_product_id|last_timestamp|time_create|last_timestamp|time_create|
+----------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
|               3|             4|          4|             4|          4|
|               2|             2|          2|             2|          2|
+----------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+-----------+
```

The inner join yields the intersection of df1 and df2 based on the *store_product_id*